# Creation of Alphabets

Tags: writing-systems, terminology

If the creation of languages ​​is called language invention what is the creation of writing systems called?

I don't think it's called Lettering because when I search for that on the net, I see that this is the creation of fonts. I would like to know what the practice or hobby of creating new writing systems is called.

> Si a la creación de lenguajes se le llama conlanging como se le llama
> a la creación de alfabetos?
>
> No creo que sea Lettering porque cuando busco sobre eso en la red veo
> que es la creación de tipografías. Quisiera saber como se llama a la
> práctica o hobby de crear nuevos sistemas de escritura.

Comment: Sorry questions here need to be asked in English. Can you translate this?

Comment: El idioma de este sitio de Stack Exchange es el inglés. Publique su pregunta en inglés, o con una traducción al inglés, si desea recibir ayuda aquí.   The language of this Stack Exchange site is English. Please post your question in English, or with an English translation, if you wish to receive help here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English.  Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no está en inglés.

Comment: @elemtilas If you're going to edit in a translation, you need to fix the question title too.

Comment: On reading this, I wondered whether "graphopoeia", by analogy with "glossopoeia"/"mythopoeia", was in use (or whether it might catch on if proposed). Not that "neography" is deficient, but it's also in use for [novel orthographies in existing scripts](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195304794.001.0001/acprof-9780195304794-chapter-4). But it turns out "graphopoeia" has also seen use, for "visual onomatopoeia": (calligraphic) writing that resembles what it describes.

Answer (score 7):

**Neography**
As with language invention, there are different names for fashioning writing systems.

While "conscirpt" and other "con-" forms are current, their problems are numerous. [Neography](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neography) is a well known term even beyond the art of language invention, well predating and certainly looking & sounding better than the alternatives.

---

> **Neografía**
> Al igual que con la invención del lenguaje, existen diferentes
> términos para diseñar sistemas de escritura.
>
> Aunque las formas "conscirpt" y otras del tipo "con-" son términos actuales, sus
> problemas son numerosos. La **neografía** es un término bien conocido
> incluso más allá del arte de la invención del lenguaje, y es mas anterior y
> ciertamente luciendo y sonando mejor que las alternativas.

Answer (score 1):

"Writing systems" are also called "scripts", so analogous to "language invention", you could call it "script invention".

However, the creation of languages as a hobby is also called "conlanging", from "conlang", shortened from "constructed language". By analogy, "constructed scripts" are sometimes called "conscripts", and the process of inventing them "conscripting". Note that while "conscripts" is pronounced with the same stress pattern whether you are referring to constructed scripts or individuals forced into government military service, the verb form moves the emphasis from "conSCRIPT" to "CONscript", and the participle form "CONscripting", when referring to the creation of writing systems.